# Gerrit Trigger for new patch set through scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, gerrit-trigger

We have integrated Gerrit Code Review with Jenkins through Gerrit Trigger plugin, So with free style job able to validate each patch set pushed to gerrit. It is working perfectly.

Now we have requirement to change to Jenkins Scripted pipeline. So for the same i have tried the following,

1. Created pipeline Job in Jenkins.
2. Enabled Gerrit Trigger section and included one repository.
3. Under pipeline section stage added for repository check out.
4. Next stage included to launch docker container.
5. Final stage included for Maven build.

Here the approach is if build finished successfully it has to set (+1) else (-1) need to set automatically. But i couldn't succeeded. Let me know whether my approach is right? If wrong please suggest me the best way.

The idea is to use scripted pipeline and docker container to verify all new patch set.

Answer (score 0):

Auto voting of specific label onto your gerrit review can be setup with the gerrit_trigger server configuration that you have in Jenkins.

Check if you have configured the same under /gerrit-trigger/
Gerrit Servers - Edit server configuration - Gerrit Reporting Values